# AJAX POST request returns HTML code in alert()

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post, alert

I have this AJAX `post` request:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'gestioneFotografie.php', //The current page
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: {
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
   },
   dataType: 'text',   
   success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
   }
});
```

The problem is that the alert looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Well what are you returning in the post back?

Comment: What JS framework are you using? jQuery?

Comment: So your php file is returning a whole html document which is what the alert is showing. If you do not want html, do not return html.

Comment: The posting page and the responding page are the same (*cf.* comment "//The current page"). I guess that there must be a bug in the PHP code. It should process the AJAX `POST` request, if any, in priority and then exit in returning a text string (no HTML output).

Comment: If you're posting JSON, you need to `JSON.stringify()` the `data`

Comment: @Phil, As I understand from https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, posting JSON-formatted data should be OK because jQuery will convert them to a query string.

Comment: @Éric jQuery will only stringify an object to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. OP has specified a content-type of `application/json` so they should be using `data: JSON.stringify({ lat, lng })`

Comment: @Matt you'll need to show what your PHP script is doing

Comment: @Phil, OK, thank you, indeed I overlooked the `contentType`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your comment `//The current page` that `gestioneFotografie.php` is both the posting page and the responding page.
Hence `gestioneFotografie.php` is mainly an HTML interface, it additionally processes the data posted with AJAX **by itself to itself**.

You are expecting a raw text string as a response, as implied by `dataType: 'text'` and by the fact that you are, knowingly I suppose, using a simple `alert()` function to display the response.

The fact that the alert box displays HTML let me suppose that `gestioneFotografie.php` fails in one or several of these steps:

1. catch the posted data
2. process them (after a safety check)
3. output a raw text response
4. `exit` before outputting anything else (including HTML)

In conclusion, you should make sure that `gestioneFotografie.php` has a global structure similar to this:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['lat'], $_POST['lng'])   &&   mySanityCheck($_POST['lat'], $_POST['lng']) === 'safe' ) {
    $string = myDataProcessor($_POST['lat'], $_POST['lng']);
    exit($string);
}

// The rest of the code, including default HTML.
?>
```